# SQL query to check whether a date exists between two dates

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I need to check whether a date exists between two dates.
The Query I am writing is

```
SELECT * FROM INTF_ORDER_HEADER WHERE ORDER_DATE BETWEEN SYSDATE – 30 AND SYSDATE
```

But it doesn't work and showing error:

```
SQL Error [911] [22019]: ORA-00911: invalid character
```

How can I fix this? I am using ORACLE11g database.

Comment: I think that might be a  `-`  try to use `SYSDATE - 30`

Answer (score 0):

Use `-` (ASCII 45)  and not the UTF-8 character `–`.